# Clarification regarding setContentView

Tags: android, setcontentview

What is difference between:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);        
TextView txtView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
```

And

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
setContentView(textView);
```

I found these two pieces of code. In first the `setContentView` has a I'd passed to it about layout. And in second case it has a view passed as argument. Is textView also an id. I think the difference is that in first case, it is layout of activity_main as described in XML file(which contains textView as well) and in second case it is id of textView. Tell me if I am correct.

Also tell me what does 'this' refer to here. Why we are using  `findViewById` in first case?

Answer (score 1):

`Activity.setContentView()` has 2 signatures. One is taking a layout id as parameter, the other is taking a View as parameter. There is actually a third one taking a View and ViewGroup.LayoutParam as input.

All three methods take what they get (a View or a layout to inflate) and set it as their root element. So in short: There is no real difference here. Just a few options the developer can choose from to tell the Activity about its root UI element

Also see: [setContentView description](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#setContentView(android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams))

The line `TextView txtView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);` is then searching for a TextView with the id "text" within the Activitys Content (in that case every view in R.layout.activity_main).

The line `TextView textView = new TextView(this);` is creating a new TextView programmatically instead of inflating a layout xml. The `this` parameter is a Context instance. A Context instance is always needed to create a View. An Activity is a Context.

Comment: Can you please explain what does `this `refer to

Comment: Thanks! So that means in second case I don't need to add textView in xml

Comment: Yes. in the second case the TextView is actually the whole content of the Activity. You would achieve the same result when you have an xml with just a TextView in it and set this xml via `setContentView()`

Answer (score 1):

In the first code,

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);        
TextView txtView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
```

you are setting the content view of the container and then trying to access the view with ID - text.

For ex:

```
<RelativeLayout android:height="match_parent"
android:width="match_parent">
<TextView
android:id="@+id/text" 
android:text="Hello"
android:height="wrap_content"
android:width="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In this layout file TextView has the id - text
So,in order to access the textview programatically, we make use of findViewById() t to get reference to view.

```
TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.text);
```

now we can make use of this view reference to make changes to the view.
For example we can change text like,

```
textView.setText("This is a test");
```

As far as

```
TextView textView2 = new TextView(this);
```

is concerned, you're creating a TextView dynamically. This can be added to the parent container as and when required.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please explain what does` this` refer to here and do we need to add textView layout in XML for second case?

Comment: this refers to current Context. In this case `this` refers to the application context. For inflating a view we need Context,so that's why we pass the application context.

Comment: You dont need to have XML layout for second case. Textview can be dynamically created and set as content view.

Comment: What would be the Id of the  textView in second case? If I want to set a string value to textView?

Comment: No ID will be set when creating a TextView programmatically. If u want you can set the ID using `setId()`.

Comment: So what will be then the value of textView?

Comment: Since you already have a reference you can set the value of textview using `textview.setText()` method.

Answer (score 0):

When you're using the following:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);        
TextView txtView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
```

you're using the `activity_main` layout as the content of the activity. whenever you're trying to bind the view with `findViewByid()`, it only search for the views inside the layout and will giving you an error if you're trying to bind views outside the layout. See [setContentView (int layoutResID)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#setContentView(int)) for details.

---

When you're using the following:

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
setContentView(textView);
```

You're creating a TextView with the activity (this) as the **context** with `new TextView(this);`. Please be noted that you always need a context whenever you're creating a View.

Then with `setContentView(textView);` you're setting the `textView` as the sole content of the activity. See [setContentView (View view)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#setContentView(android.view.View)) for details.